# SSIS package fails when run as scheduled job but succeeds if run stand alone

Tags: ssis

I've a Master package which has the scheduling of all the Jobs to run on a daily basis. Couple of my packages are failing when deployed on the server (its a file system deployment). The SSIS packages runs fine on my development machine or if run stand alone on the server., but strangely they fail when run as part of the scheduled job. I've SQL logging enabled and the error is pretty straightforward to interpret and sort out, however when I try to debug in the development environment it runs fine. I have an environment variable which holds the connection string and the SSIS package deployment is a file deployment with SQL logging enabled for all the Jobs. The problem is Im unable to replicate the error on my dev machine as the import takes place without any issue but its only when it runs as part of the scheduled job when it fails. Also it truncates the table fine but while importing the data it fails with data truncation error.

I'm unable to figure out what I'm missing here, any help will be very much appreciated.

SSIS sql error log from dbo.sysssislog table :

Anz_Isis_Cfv_Import_TblRefSDGPLHierarchyBU  2014-11-14 08:08:33.000 2014-11-14 08:08:33.000 Beginning of package execution.
Anz_Isis_Cfv_Import_TblRefSDGPLHierarchyBU  2014-11-14 08:08:33.000 2014-11-14 08:08:33.000 Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "vcrFlgActive" returned status value 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.".
Anz_Isis_Cfv_Master 2014-11-14 08:08:33.000 2014-11-14 08:08:33.000 Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "vcrFlgActive" returned status value 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.".
Anz_Isis_Cfv_Import_TblRefSDGPLHierarchyBU  2014-11-14 08:08:33.000 2014-11-14 08:08:33.000 The "output column "vcrFlgActive" (71)" failed because truncation occurred, and the truncation row disposition on "output column "vcrFlgActive" (71)" specifies failure on truncation. A truncation error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.
Anz_Isis_Cfv_Master 2014-11-14 08:08:33.000 2014-11-14 08:08:33.000 The "output column "vcrFlgActive" (71)" failed because truncation occurred, and the truncation row disposition on "output column "vcrFlgActive" (71)" specifies failure on truncation. A truncation error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.
Anz_Isis_Cfv_Import_TblRefSDGPLHierarchyBU  2014-11-14 08:08:33.000 2014-11-14 08:08:33.000 An error occurred while processing file "\Svrau530csm02.oceania.corp.anz.com\infra\Markets Finance\CFV IN\tblRefSD_GPL_Hierachy_BU_20141114.csv" on data row 2.
Anz_Isis_Cfv_Master 2014-11-14 08:08:33.000 2014-11-14 08:08:33.000 An error occurred while processing file "\Svrau530csm02.oceania.corp.anz.com\infra\Markets Finance\CFV IN\tblRefSD_GPL_Hierachy_BU_20141114.csv" on data row 2.
Anz_Isis_Cfv_Import_TblRefSDGPLHierarchyBU  2014-11-14 08:08:33.000 2014-11-14 08:08:33.000 SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on component "Flat File Source" (1) returned error code 0xC0202092.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
Anz_Isis_Cfv_Master 2014-11-14 08:08:33.000 2014-11-14 08:08:33.000 SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on component "Flat File Source" (1) returned error code 0xC0202092.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
Anz_Isis_Cfv_Import_TblRefSDGPLHierarchyBU  2014-11-14 08:08:33.000 2014-11-14 08:08:33.000 End of package execution.

Answer (score 0):

The error message "The data conversion for column "vcrFlgActive" returned status value 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page." would point to a data related problem: I would assume on the server, there is some data that is larger than the target column allows, but this is not there in your development environment.

E. g. a string of length 23 and your column `crFlgActive` has an SSIS `DT_STR` data type of length 20.

One way to find the data causing problems would be to configure the destination component to redirect records causing problems instead of failing. The redirection could be to a table, or maybe even just a CSV or Excel file.

Comment: hi FrankPI - the table in dev and production are identical. Also I use the RedGate to deploy the scripts and table objects to minimise any manual error between the data types. How come the same data when loaded in dev without any issue cause problem in production ?

Comment: @K.S. what is this component - Anz_Isis_Cfv_Import_TblRefSDGPLHierarchyBU?  A flat file source or something else?

Comment: i'm having the exact same issue. the component i'm using is a flat file source

Comment: @Charlie And have you tried re-directing the erroneous rows?

Comment: I have the same issue with flat file (CSV) source. Works fine in BIDS, but will not run under Agent.